# How to remove preceding and trailing whitespaces of Hyphen in a String, using Java or Regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, string

How to remove all spaces between Hyphens and preceding and trailing word in following string?

```
String s = "O Jesus  -   Jesus Jesus-O -     Jesus  - O -O";
s.replaceAll("  -   ", "-"); <- This only replaces first spacy-hyphen with hyphen
```

We are getting other search words with Hyphen at unknown place between number of whitespaces. How regular expression can handle the same? Need global solution for same.

Output required:

```
"O Jesus-Jesus Jesus-O-Jesus-O-O";
```

Tried splitting and trimming and joining back but code looks rubbish. Need some shortcut.

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\s*-\\s*", "-");` shoud do!

Comment: @YCF_L: Updated description for output.

Comment: And what have you tried? You just dumped requirements?!

Comment: Tried splitting and trimming and joining back but code looks rubbish :(

Answer (score 3):

A regex will allow you to specify an unknown number of spaces:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s*-\\s*", "-");
```

where `\\s*` means 0 or more whitespaces.

The output will be: `O Jesus-Jesus Jesus-O-Jesus-O-O`

Comment: Thanks a lot. In another situation, Is there any way to avoid removing whitespaces for a Hyphen which is already connected to word like "O- God  - My - God" <- Here O is already connected to a word so i don't want to remove its whitespace and want output as "O- God-My-God"/

Comment: `\\s*` --> `\\s+`

Comment: This solution disregards the "preceding *and* trailing word" requirement. It will replace `- Yes.` with `-Yes.` and `No -` with `No-`. Maybe that is not a problem here.